# Ofbiz install freezes on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, virtualbox

I am trying to install 'ofbiz' on a virtualbox guest running Ubuntu 16.04.

The install goes fine until it gets to...

> Configuring > 53/54 projects > root project > Resolving dependencies ':runtim

...then the install stays at that point until you crash out.

Does anyone know why?

Thanks

Comment: What source are you using for 'OfBiz' and which set of instructions are you following to install it?

Comment: I am using the apache-ofbiz-16.11.03.zip file from Apache and following the instructions on the README file in the zip.

Comment: Did you download and install Java directly from oracle?

Comment: Yes, Java was downloaded from Oracle